# Add 'JSON-LD' Tag to 'JSON' Tag

Tags: discussion

JSON-LD is just another flavor of JSON, and while I do concede it has larger applications in the open data space, at the end of the day, it is still JSON.

There are six [JSON-LD tags](https://opendata.stackexchange.com/tags/json-ld/info) in use at the moment, so pointing it to the [JSON tag](https://opendata.stackexchange.com/tags/json/info) shouldn't cause very much confusion whatsoever.

Note: I came across this while editing the JSON tag to define JSON-LD as well; whatever the community decides to do, I'll edit the tags accordingly.

Answer (score 2):

I created a synonym and merged tags:

- from source [json-ld](https://opendata.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/json-ld)
- to target [json](https://opendata.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/json)

So like you say, we should use [json](https://opendata.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/json)

Comment: nice. could i have just done that? should i have just done that?

Comment: maybe, although I think the reputation limit is set too high for our small site and only the mods can do it at the moment. (this was only my second tag synonym)

Comment: https://opendata.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/suggest-tag-synonyms But before being a mod I think I always needed at least some reputation with that tag, which isn't realistic for new tags without many questions.

Comment: thanks @philshem i appreciate the information!

Comment: Having done the deed, isn't it common practice to tag the question as [tag:status-completed] ?

Answer (score 1):

It is not clear to me that these tags should be merged.

json is a widely used data format and json-LD (linked data) is a formal mechanism of cross referencing vocabularies and concepts to specific definitions and contexts. I predict that as json-LD becomes more widely used, it will be clear more why the tags should be disambiguated.

> JSON-LD (JavaScript Object Notation for Linked Data), is a method of encoding Linked Data using JSON.

- https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSON-LD

Comment: pretty sure everyone in this question is in agreement about everything save having two tags. even in agreement about the future; the point of merging is that there are not very many questions regarding json-ld currently. future proofing is always nice, but there is no way to tell if/when json-ld questions will increase in the future.